# RCP exportWizard remove unnecessary items

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp

I've add an Standart EXPORT action on my FileMenu:

```
addToMenuAndRegister(menu, ActionFactory.EXPORT.create(window));
```

And created a contribution wizard:

```
<extension
 id="exportSQL"
 point="org.eclipse.ui.exportWizards"
 name="SQL скрипты создания документа СУФД">
      <wizard
            category="ru.otr.cactuss.model.editor.wizard2"
            icon="icons/database.png"
            class="ru.otr.cactuss.wizard.sqlexport.SQLExportWizard"
            id="ru.otr.cactuss.wizard.sqlexport.SQLExportWizard"
            name="SQL скрипты создания документа СУФД">
      </wizard>
</extension>
```

And it's all works fine, but there is 3 standart export actions in general folder: export as Archive File, File System and Preferences. At least two of them (2 first) are highly irrelevent to my project and I want to get rid of them. The question is - how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [Filtering large user interfaces](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Fguide%2Fworkbench_scalability.htm), especially the part of [expression-based activities](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Fguide%2Fworkbench_advext_activities.htm). That should do the trick and can even be used to remove other sorts of items such as views, commands and perspectives...

Comment: hi @Tonny Madsen, Does it also work in Eclipse 4 environment. My original question is this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/10043190/948268 .

Comment: @KuldeepJain We have not yet encountered this problem in a 4.x setting, so I cannot tell you...