# Hide Coolbar/Toolbar items/Preference pages in Eclipse RCP application (Eclipse e4)

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, xtext

In our Eclipse RCP application (using **Eclipse 3.7**) I had overridden `WorkbenchWindowAdvisor.postWindowCreate()` method, to hide the unwanted Coolbar/Toolbar items like *File*, *Run* etc. menus and *Run Last Tool*, *Search* etc. toolbar buttons and it was working fine. Now I have moved my code to Eclipse e4 4.1.2 and when I run my RCP application now it gets launched but it is showing these unwanted Coolbar/Toolbar items.

On some digging into the issue I found out that `WorkbenchWindowAdvisor.postWindowCreate()` method is not used in `e4` and it does not get called at all. So what is the alternative way of doing this in Eclipse e4?

**EDIT:**
 I also want to mention that in my RCP application I am having `Xtext` plugin.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative way is using Eclipse Activities.
Check my question here: 
[RCP exportWizard remove unnecesary items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9655667/rcp-exportwizard-remove-unnecesary-items)

Comment: Thanks for your reply @execc, I will try this. Does it also work in Eclipse 4 environment?

Answer (score 1):

You can:
a) use a custom Legacy.e4xmi file which has none of those items
b) use a model processor to remove those items programmatically from the model

Comment: Thanks for our reply @tomsontom. I have tried using a custom `Legacy.e4xmi` file, but have no clue about how to edit that, neither found any documentation about it. I tried to modify it but still seeing `Run` and `Search` menus. Could you please let me know about what to change in `Legacy.e4xmi` file to remove the menubar all together and some of the toolbar items. I also want to mention that in my RCP application I am having an `Xtext` plugin.

Comment: I installed `e4 tools` on my Eclipse 4.2 and was able to change stuff in `Legacy.e4xmi` file. But even if I make the menu bar `invisible` of mark `toBeRendered` as false, and then first time when I launch the Application, it does not show the Menu bar, which is correct, but when I relaunch it without making any change then it starts showing the Menu bar with `Search` and `Run`  menu items.