# How to hide toolbar in Eclipse 4.2?

Tags: eclipse, toolbar

The toolbar is of no use for me, it occupies space, I use shortcuts to achieve all functions the toolbar provide. In Eclipse 3.7 we can right click the toolbar and hit "hide toolbar", but how to do that in Eclipse 4?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Menu was gone but the command seems to be available still now.
Preferences > General > Keys
Type "toggle t" in filter text, then "Toggle Toolbar Visibility" will appear. It seems to work when some key is assigned.

Comment: Awesome, actually i type "toggle toolbar" in quick access box and press enter, the toolbar disappear, including the quick access box--just what i need. Thank you.

Answer (score 12):

`> Window > Hide Toolbar`

(I'm running 4.2.1.)

Comment: That removes the entire toolbar. He needs to remove specific unusable items from toolbar.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is what he wanted :-)

Comment: For recent versions it is `> Window > Appearance > Hide Toolbar`

Answer (score 1):

In 4.7.2 you can use the menu items: `Window -> Appearance -> Hide Toolbar` & `Window -> Appearance -> Show Toolbar` to toggle toolbar visibility.

Answer (score 1):

In `4.9.0` you can open `Window > Perspective > Customize Perspective` via the top menu. Here you can either hide a complete tool bar group and even show/hide single icons. Me, I reduced it to show only one single line of symbols, so that I have more space for the editors below.

The `Customize Perspective` function has been introduced long time ago in Eclipse, so I guess it is available for your version.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can do it programatically like this:

```
@Override
public void postWindowOpen() {
    hideCoolbar();
    super.postWindowOpen();
}

private void hideCoolbar() {
    try {
        IHandlerService service = (IHandlerService) PlatformUI
                .getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow()
                .getService(IHandlerService.class);
        if (service != null)
            service.executeCommand("org.eclipse.ui.ToggleCoolbarAction",
                    null);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //handle error
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if this will work, but why dont you take a look at this.

[Hide Coolbar/Toolbar items/Preference pages in Eclipse RCP application (Eclipse e4)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10043190/hide-coolbar-toolbar-items-preference-pages-in-eclipse-rcp-application-eclipse)

Answer (score -1):

```
WorkbenchWindow w = (WorkbenchWindow)HandlerUtil
     .getActiveSite(event)
     .getWorkbenchWindow();
w.setPerspectiveBarVisible(false);
```