# Remove "Quick Access" entry in Eclipse Juno

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

How do I remove the "Quick Access" text entry from Juno's CDT toolbar? I never use it and it consumes valuable space on my laptop screen.

Comment: I'm using my own plugin, http://sourceforge.jp/downloads/users/1/1259/jp.sourceforge.pdt_tools.HideQuickAccess_1.0.0.201206301941.jar (drop it into eclipse/dropins folder)

Comment: Have they removed the Quick Access textbox in Juno SR1 (Eclipse 4.2.1)? Or somehow made it invisible by default? I can't find any option and I no longer need the JAR linked in comment above to fix this.

Comment: This download link is dead, could you provide an updated one?

Comment: I've saved the plugin, and uploaded here, in case anyone still want it. I've just tested it in Eclipse Kepler and it works great too! http://goo.gl/PkvBW

Comment: @ADTC Still present in v4.2.2

Comment: Nice removes it and fixes the blank space created by it.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

This bug  [Make "Quick access" optional and hidden by default](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=362420) covers it. It looks like it is not currently possible, I suggest you add your interest to the bug.

Comment: what a big, big mess..and it is 2014

Comment: This has been fixed in luna. See below

Answer (score 41):

I looked for an answer to this question because Quick Access took a full row in the toolbar. Instead of removing it (Which requires too much hacking for my taste), I just removed a few toolbar buttons that I didn't use anyway, and the Quick Access shifted up among the rest of the buttons taking only an acceptable amount of space.

There is really no need for that many buttons for any one perspective. They should fit unless your screen is tiny. Customise this in **Window -> Customize Prespective...**

Comment: This was helpful. You can also right click on the "Java" ,"Debug" "Python", etc Perspective switch icons and toggle the setting to not "show text." This will further save space on the toolbar and prevent Quick access from pushing into its own row

Comment: thanks for idea, worked great for me, anyway there are toolbar buttons I never clicked (keyboard shortcuts do the job much faster for me)

Comment: In addition to removing toolbar buttons, one can hide the text of the perspectives (right click and uncheck `Show text`). For example, `Team Synchronizing` takes up a lot of space. The icon may be enough for many Eclipse users.

Answer (score 36):

Here is a quick hack which doesn't require any plugin installation, instead you just need to add a few lines to your current layout's CSS file. Works perfectly for me in v4.2.2

Navigate to `<ECLIPSE_HOME>/plugins/org.eclipse.platform_<VERSION>/css` then open up the CSS file of whichever layout you are using, e.g. mine was `e4_default.css`. Now append the following snippet to the file:

```
#SearchField {
   visibility:hidden;
}
```

Now just restart Eclipse and the box is gone.

`*Edit`

It appears that the layout file `e4_basestyle.css` is used universally, regardless of your current layout. Thus you should be able to add the above snippet to that file and this fix will be persistent, even if you change layouts.

Comment: this is great, thanks! 
Regarding which css file to edit: it seems that e4_basestyle.css is always used, so adding the code there should work for all layouts.

Comment: @morgwai Great thanks for that, I'll update my answer with that info

Comment: Worked for me perfectly in Eclipse 4.3.1 on 32-bit Linux Mint 15!

Comment: Sorta worked... it removed the quick access but now i still have an extra row blank it still seems to be formatting for it as if it was there

Comment: same problem on ubuntu as noted by @JPM. it's hidden alright, but I still have all that unused space on the top row.

Comment: I set the SearchField to hidden|collapse, which made it re-appear but all buttons were on the same row. I switched it back to just hidden, now it's gone, without the extra toolbar row. I do suspect this is just temporary and the quick access field will reappear soon.

Comment: This doesn't work for me in 4.2.2 M20130204-1200, tried both _default and _basestyle.

Answer (score 11):

In Luna this has been fixed.

You can just right click on Quick Access toolbar and click hide to hide it. Refer last few comments in https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=362420

Comment: (Provided you manage to right-click on the magic spot.) Thanks +1

Comment: To add to this- you don't right-click on the quick access toolbar, or you'll get the menu with things like copy/paste/etc. (At least, this is the case on Windows.) You have to right-click outside the textbox but still in the toolbar (i was able to do it by going just under the text box).

Answer (score 5):

A solution inspired from :
https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=319991

(With eclipse Juno 4.2) Just add this piece of code to your `ApplicationWorkbenchWindowAdvisor` class and call the method from `preWindowOpen()`.

```
private void hideQuickAccess() { 
        UIJob job = new UIJob("hide quick access") {
            @Override
            public IStatus runInUIThread(IProgressMonitor monitor) {
                IWorkbenchWindow window = PlatformUI.getWorkbench()
                        .getActiveWorkbenchWindow();
                if (window instanceof WorkbenchWindow) {
                    MTrimBar topTrim = ((WorkbenchWindow) window).getTopTrim();
                for (MTrimElement element : topTrim.getChildren()) {
                    if ("SearchField".equals(element.getElementId())) {                     
                        ((Control) element.getWidget()).dispose();
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            return Status.OK_STATUS;
        }
    };
    job.schedule();
```

It might not work unless changing the accessibility rule of the `org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.workbench.source_0.10.1.v20120523-1955.jar`.
To change this option, go to the Java build Path menu, find the jar, expand it and the option will appear.

NB: I'm not sure about the entailment of this last change, it could be 'not clean'.

Answer (score 5):

Check out this plugin: https://github.com/atlanto/eclipse-4.x-filler#hide-quick-access-plug-in

Works with Eclipse Kepler release.

> This plug-in adds a functionality to hide/show Quick Access textbox in the main toolbar.
>
> Window ☞ Hide Quick Access

Comment: Worked like a charm. Entere the update URL https://raw.github.com/atlanto/eclipse-4.x-filler/master/pdt_tools.eclipse-4.x-filler.update/ in Eclipse's "Install new Software" Window and you can install it directly from Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Solution for Version: Oxygen Release (4.7.0):

1. Save the icons you are constantly using by dragging them off the "Toolbar" e.g. left/right/under to the Editor.
2. Then toggle: Window > Appearance > Hide/Show Toolbar
   Done. :)

Answer (score -2):

Type "toggle toolbar" in the quick access window (yes, that very thing that annoys us) and it'll be gone. [C.f.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11454949/how-to-hide-toolbar-in-eclipse-4-2)

Comment: I'd vote -1 (no rep sadly). This tip removed the entire toolbar! I just wanted to hide the quick access box. I had to dig here and there to bring the toolbar back, and now many buttons are missing (not that I use them, but still, a tip that not only doesn't do what's intended, but also destroys stuff needs a vote down).

Comment: this method is for toolbar haters

Comment: Your don't deserve the downvotes IMO, you can always turn the toolbar back on with Window > Show Toolbar.

Comment: @ADTC this tip doesn't destroy anything, it hides the toolbar (one way of removing the Quick Access box) and is entirely reversible. If toolbar items are missing when you show it again, that's a bug.

Comment: @jaybee Why does he not deserve the downvotes? The question is "how to remove the quick access entry" not "how to remove my entire toolbar". He doesn't even clarify what his "solution" is actually doing in his answer. This is a perfect example of an answer that should be downvoted.

Comment: Turns out this is what I wanted to do, not remove quick access. Saved at least 20 pixels, yay.