# Remove quick access filed from Eclipse RCP application

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, rcp

How to remove quick access filed  from Eclipse RCP application create in Eclipse Kepler(4.3)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove "Quick Access" entry in Eclipse Juno](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11549283/remove-quick-access-entry-in-eclipse-juno)

Answer (score 1):

In an Eclipse RCP application you can remove it using CSS.

In your Default css file add the following entry :

```
#SearchField {
    visibility: hidden; 
}
```

To add a css you can add a property called **applicationCSS** to your product extensiton point and refer to the CSS file you created.

**More Info :** http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Eclipse4CSS/article.html#css_fixed